# Get tables from wikipedia with headers in python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get multiple tables from a page from wikipedia, for example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2016_squads

When I try:

```
import pandas 
df = pandas.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2016_squads")
```

Then I get a list of tables, but I do not have a way to know which table belongs to which team. For example:
[image]

What would be ideal is, if I can have a dict, which goes like follows:

```
{ '<Name of country A>':  '<Country A table in dataframe format>', 
  '<Name of country B>':  '<Country B table in dataframe format>' }
```

I looked at the following libraries as well:

1. [Wikipedia-api](https://pypi.org/project/Wikipedia-API/): I did not find any features to handle table here
2. [Wikipedia](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/): This one seems really old and probably depreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. The main thing to realize is that the `df` in your code is really a list of tables - 29 to be exact, of which only the first 24 are relevant.

Once that's sorted out, you also need to get the list of countries for the tables. So one of the ways to handle this (and there may be other):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2016_squads"
req = requests.get(url)
tables = pd.read_html(url) #or pd.read_html(req.text)
soup = bs(req.text,'lxml')
countries = soup.select('h3 span.mw-headline')[:24] #using css selectors
```

At this point, if you

```
for country, df in zip(countries, tables):
    print(country.text,df)
```

you get country/team pairs which you can assign to a dictionary or whatever.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for.